# All test related tasks running in development envrionment -- Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, development-environment, environment

When I run a task that should be running in the test environment, it is running in development.  This includes `rake test:(units/functionals/integration)` and `rake db:test:prepare`.  A side effect is that it is overwriting my database every time I run tests.  I renamed the development database, and now it keeps complaining that it can't find my old database (the one in `database.yml`).  The environment is being set to development in `require 'rails'` at the top of my `application.rb`.  Am I missing some sort of simple configuration?

Edit: If I run my tests appended with `RAILS_ENV=test`, they are run in the test environment.  However, I can't actually run them because I have pending migrations (all of them).  Running `rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test` gives me the same pending-migrations error.

Update: The database is migrated, and my tests are going.  I still feel like running my tests every time with `RAILS_ENV=test` isn't the correct way to be doing it

Update: I found that if I change `def env` in railties to default to 'test', the environment becomes test.  That is

```
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` instead of the other options that I had tried.  I'm still not sure why the other ones didn't work, but I'm going to call this question solved.

So simple...

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `ENV ||= "test"` to `ENV = "test"` in your `spec_helper`

If you are using Capybara and have rails server running in development mode then Capybara will use that instead of booting up a test instance.

A fix can be found here:

[How to use the test database with Capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662554/how-to-use-the-test-database-with-capybara)

Comment: I'm using Test:Unit, but at the top of my test_helper, I've tried `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]  = "test"`, `RAILS_ENV = "test"`, and `ENV = "test"`.  None seem to be working.  Also, I am not running a server concurrently (I don't think).  I ran `top` and didn't see anything that looked like a rails server.  Also, I tried the fix on the linked page, and it didn't make any difference